# Dynamic Property File Loading in Spring based on the URL Argument for every request for data validation

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working in a environment(in **Spring**, version **4.x**) which needs to load/change the property files based on the URL argument for every request.

After successful build of application, for the first request I need to get an argument from the URL, and based on that argument I have to load the properties i.e, my application has to run with new properties and I'll be using this property file for validation.

But the problem is based on the configuration all the property files are loading before getting the URL argument and I am not able to load the property file dynamically after every request.

For example, if I am having two customers using my product and both have different set of rules(based on which, validation needs to be performed), from there request I'll get to know which customer is requesting and which set of rules I should apply for validation(for which, I am thinking of using property files).

I tried using different ways(but not working): http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/#usage

Similar question: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/119875-dynamic-property-file-loading-in-spring-based-on-the-url-argument

Comment: what property file contains? Is it required for spring configuration?

Comment: Property file is required for data validation and contains validation rules, lets say, minimum length , max length & some regular expression (for mail-id or DOB validation).